# How to do Python Requests and bs4 for public data stats for a game?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to find how to get the level of a player from krunker.io/social.html with python requests yet it never seems to find the div LVL when its definitely there on the webpage? here is my code so far

`

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time

from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = "https://krunker.io/social.html?p=profile&q=Dragon"  # Replace with the actual URL

# Create a UserAgent object

user_agent = UserAgent()

# Make the request with a random User-Agent

headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent.random}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Introduce a delay (adjust the sleep duration as needed)

# Parse the HTML content

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

time.sleep(3)

# Check for the presence of captcha elements

captcha_elements = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'captcha-class'})  # Replace 'captcha-class' with the actual class used for captcha

if captcha_elements:

    print("Captcha elements found. Please handle captcha.")

else:

    # Find the div and strong elements

    stat_tab_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'statTabB0'})

    if stat_tab_div:

        strong_elements = stat_tab_div.find_all('strong')

        for strong_element in strong_elements:

            print(strong_element.text)

    else:

        print("Couldn't find the 'statTabB0' div.")
```

I am expecting it to return the level stats in the terminal, for example the profile level for user Dragon is lvl 12.

Comment: Since there is a captcha, I'm guessing you will need `selenium` nut just `requests`.

Comment: `requests` cannot process javascript.  This is likely the reason.

Comment: I really dont want to use selenium, is there a module that does process javascript?